# Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, feeds, importing-exporting

I am using the Feeds Import module as described in [Drupal as an interface for users to Add/Edit/Search a database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59385/drupal-as-an-interface-for-users-to-add-edit-search-a-database).

When we import, we get the following error:

> Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term

Why does that error message appear?

Answer (score 2):

This error is caused when there is no ***Vocabulary*** selected in the ***Term reference*** fields of the content type into which feed import is performed.

Go to the [Manage fields](http://www.domain.com/admin/structure/types/manage/page/fields) of your content type into which you are importing. Check all the ***Term reference*** fields and reconfirm that in the ***Field Settings***, correct ***Vocabulary*** is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my entity (term) did not have the property `vocabulary_machine_name`.

It was `["vocabulary_machine_name"] => NULL` when it should have the right **vocabulary_machine_name**, in this case 'forum'.

So a made sure the term has it:

```
                        $term->name = ...;
                        $term->vid = ...;
                        $term->vocabulary_machine_name = 'forum'; //here
                        $term->format = ...;
```